# How to install pre-built binaries in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04

Im trying to install Fabio github.com/fabiolb/fabio in Ubuntu, after downloaded fabio-1.5.9-go1.10.2-linux_386 from

```
https://github.com/fabiolb/fabio/releases
```

I can't find any installation instruction for Ubuntu, is there a convention for install pre-built binaries?

On Mac after install using 'brew install fabio', I can run the executable fabio command from terminal.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is too vague to help you. It fails silently? It throws an error message? It bakes you a cake instead? Please edit your question to clearly explain the clues that lead you to believe it's not working.

Comment: hey, basically there is no installation instruction, so I assume there are conventions to install pre-built binaries that I don't know about?

Comment: Are you running a 32-bit or 64-bit system? Did you chmod the downloaded file to make it executable? (If not, then you would be getting helpful error messages)